# How does memory sum together?

Tags: macos, memory, memory-pressure

as per the photo attaches as an example. I wanted to recall how physical ram sums together. what types of memory go with each other to equal the sum total of the physical memory. (also in case of unified memory where gpu shares cpu memory since I have a M1 Mac)

What would go in the used memory category? what would go in the available memory category? Where do these all fit in (App memory, active, wired, inactive, compressed, cached, free memory) (in case of M1 - GPU Memory).

can anyone explain this, I dont need to know what the definition of each type of memory are I know all that. just want it in the photo example form since I feel its missing stuff.

[image: Exmaple of what take part in the total sum of memory]

Comment: You've really got quite a few questions here. Is there one you need more than the others or a practical issue you are facing with these side questions leading up to something specific? Apple's memory summary is much more readable than whatever app you are using - can you add the official snip with an edit perhaps? https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoHoy.png

Comment: Does this Q and my A help? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/423717/is-there-a-command-line-tool-that-accurately-describes-the-amount-of-used-memory

Comment: Memory management is much more complex than just 'summing together'. Don't use tools to "free up" memory. MacOS is designed to use as much RAM as possible -- usually all of it. You only need to worry about high levels of memory compression and large amount of swap. (Neither of which appear to be shown on your app, but you'll find in Activity Monitor.)