# Calculate process memory usage as percentage

Tags: macos, command-line, memory, activity-monitor, virtual-memory

I want to calculate the **memory usage as a percentage** for some processes on the device.

That is, **how much percent of total memory a particular process is taking on the system.** (Need it for reporting some metrics for both Windows and Mac devices, so the percentage seems to be consistent among both)

With the `top` command, we get the memory usage as size (KB, MB, GB) and the value is also not the actual physical memory (RAM) used but the virtual memory (physical + swap memory).

Q1. So, if I manually calculate the memory usage percentage, what formula should I use:

- (process mem usage from top command) / (total physical memory + swap space used) * 100
- (process mem usage from top command) / (total physical memory + swap space alloted) * 100
- (process mem usage from top command) / (total physical memory) * 100

Q2. Is there any other way other than top command which only gives physical memory usage for individual processes so that I can use the third formula above?

Example: If Chrome is using 1 GB of memory, then I can say that it is using xx % of memory. But to calculate that I need the same units in the numerator (memory usage of the process) and denominator (memory available in the system).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your phrasing of these calculations confuses me since the [virtual memory model](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/317483/5472) on macOS makes these values (especially swap) transient and squishy. It feels to me you’re [trying to re-implement memory pressure](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/202746/5472) which is already [provided by the OS](https://support.apple.com/guide/activity-monitor/check-if-your-mac-needs-more-ram-actmntr34865/mac). Could you edit this to explain more the end goal you have in mind? What are you trying to do with these measures?

Comment: Also - [browse this thread for some very well written discussion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/423749/5472) on what the definitions of various measures are and how they relate to the built in tools.

Comment: Hey @bmike , thanks for the quick reply.
I have added an example at the end to explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: And sure, will take a look at the thread you shared.
Thanks !!

Comment: An additional issue with a browser is that the parent app is just that - a parent. That will spawn a slew of child processes for each open window/tab, which aren't included in the parent's figures. With only 8 tabs open in Chrome right now, I count 20 child processes, taking far more RAM than the parent alone - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvSRN.png

Comment: What do you do with this percentage when you have it? Generally, macOS manages memory very well, and you shouldn't need to do anything. Not using Chrome will of course reduce your memory use considerably, and improve your privacy!

Comment: I am fetching the RAM usage as percentage and showing it on a portal. The output format is same for all OSes (Mac / windows). So, that's why need it in percentage.

Comment: Also, I don't need it on the whole system level but on a process level. 
Like, what I need is "What percent of memory(RAM) a particular process (or a group of processes) is taking."

Comment: Yes, but what do you do once you know the value? Is this research? Unless you're actually experiencing a memory leak that's affecting performance, there's no need to watch over the memory manager. Also, by "portal", you mean a website?

Comment: Also I doubt that memory use figures for macOS, Windows and Linux are comparable ie >90% which is what a good OS aims for means different things. Also that 90% might be a large program like Final Cut or just something like notepad wioth the rest of memory used as file cache - what does that same figure mean in  those two cases

Comment: @benwiggy yes, portal means a website. This is for a metric collection tool. Memory usage for applications is one of the metrics among many and it should be percentage for all OSes.

Comment: Memory management is a lot more complex than summing together the parts. If an app is using 10% of RAM, what do you do about it?